# How do I best identify browsers and operating systems including mobiles and tablets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, analytics, user-agent

We have a scenario where we wish to analyse the visitors to our web site and determine the following:

- The operating system
- The browser
- Whether it is a mobile device
- Whether it is a tablet device

This is purely for reporting purposes to provide to our clients, and will not be used to alter the content at all for that particular device. Ideally this would be something performed server side.

The data **has** to be displayed by ourselves, so we need a tool to perform the categorisation and then hand it off to our process for storage, calculation and subsequent retrieval.

We currently use the ASP.NET HttpRequest.Browser object but the information gained is not particularly useful.

I have spent some time looking into this scenario, the most useful being [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) and [User Agent Info](http://user-agent-string.info/) .

If my understanding of the AGPL is correct then by using WURFL and agreeing to the license we would be required to provide the source code to our application to anyone who requested it. That is out of the question and the licensing costs in our scenario are too costly (approximately $50k per annum).

User Agent Info seems a good product, however to tie a core feature of a commercial application to something that may or may not be kept up to date is a risk.

What other solutions are there out there? Does anyone have any recommendations or alternatives? We are not adverse to paying licensing, as long as they are realistic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "core feature" -- is this a core feature, really? even though all you'll be doing is displaying it for reporting? Are you building a home-grown analytics suite?

Comment: Yes it is a core feature, there is no need to go into the nature of the application - simply that this is a feature and the requirement is to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation it seems that WURFL is the most complete solution for mobile browsers and the only solution I can see for tablet detection but is slightly lacking in desktop browser support. I believe this support is to be improved in the near future.

It is then a matter of deciding whether the cost is acceptable for the application in question.

Comment: One further alternative is https://51degrees.mobi/ which seemingly allows users to access WURFL through it's own API http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Blogs/tabid/212/EntryId/20/51Degrees-mobi-Mobile-Detection-Outside-of-IIS.aspx

Comment: While Andrew's comment is perhaps a bit strongly worded, the main thrust of the comment is true; this "answer" doesn't add any information to the post, unlike the others, which genuinely did.

Comment: @MarcGravell This "answer" concludes that WURFL is the best option and the decision is to be based on cost. The previous answers regarding WURFL simply questioned the fact that I had an incorrect quote and reaffirm a core issue with the site that new users cannot comment and must resort to adding answers. I have added to my answer in regards to tablets which is one of the key points.

Comment: Correcting key misunderstandings in the *pretext* of a question (for example, about having to release source-code) is more than a comment, and adds value

Comment: There is a need to release the source code in an AGPL scenario, the licensing cost is to prevent the need for this. That was the original reason for the question and this is outlined in the initial post.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the free [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) and if you need to check stuff in code, I would use the javascript called [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

you can use custom reporting in analytics http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=98527

and you can schedule sending reports:
http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57163

Comment: I will go back and outline this in the question, but one thing is we need to collate and present the information in our own application. Does Google Analytics provide an API for simply categorising the data or does it have to be collected by their JS and displayed within their UI?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/ :) and a sample http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/Analytics_DataFeed_Sample/dataFeed.cs

Answer (score 1):

Luca Passani of WURFL and ScientiaMobile here. Not sure where the original poster got the $50k quote. The reality is that we have a relatively complex pricing structure to accommodate everyone's DDR needs based on how much value WURFL actually provides to them and whether they are reselling WURFL functionality in some form (be it SaaS or bundled with own software) to third-party companies.

I can only suggest that the original poster (and whoever else is interested in licensing WURFL) takes contact with ScientiaMobile through this form:

http://www.scientiamobile.com/license

We also recommend that you save your own and our time by using real email addresses (gmail, hotmail and other virtually anonymous email addresses are not OK) and, above all, provide as truthful information as possible.

Finally, to be clear, commercial licensees are relieved from the copyleft provisions of AGPL. In addition to this, they get access to a personal customer vault with weekly snapshot of the data always available.

Thank you

Luca Passani

Comment: The $50k quote came directly from ScientiaMobile, the exact number was $4500 per month. This is based on a SaaS model with approximately 200 clients a month.

Answer (score 0):

WURFL commercial licenses do not require you to release the source code to your application.

You can find the licensing costs and restrictions [here](http://scientiamobile.com/products/#licenses)

The most expensive single commercial license is $20k, and goes as low as $1500.  Not sure where the $50k number is coming from, but I'd be happy to help if you have any licensing questions.

---

Seeing RRR's comment, further clarification is due. If your company is using WURFL as part of a SaaS service or bundled with your own software, you are effectively removing the need for your customers to license WURFL separately from ScientiaMobile. This is fine, but only as long you cover for that WURFL usage as part of your OEM license. To be clear, your customers, at that point, are not WURFl licensees, but rather authorized users of your license.

Comment: Those are single licenses, we were informed that we would need a license per client that uses our application and therefore full under the OEM license and the quote provided was around $50k per annum.